# Can't detect mouse down on MFC Picture control

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to add a picture control in a mfc dialog. I want to get the x,y coordinates of the pixel when I click on the picture control. I am using [this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24969/An-MFC-picture-control-to-dynamically-show-picture) as a reference code and following [this discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9892cd67-4ba4-4511-8de7-de80d25edbe9/click-location-within-mfc-picture-control?forum=vcgeneral) to detect the click on the picture control.

A separate class has been derived for the picture control and PreTranslateMessage has been implemented.

```
BOOL CPictureCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN && GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_BITMAP)->GetSafeHwnd() == pMsg->hwnd)
    {
        CPoint point(pMsg->pt);
        ScreenToClient(&point);

        OnLButtonDown(pMsg->wParam, point);    //passes the coordinates of the clicked Point in the dialog box
    }

    return CStatic::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);

}
```

In the main Dialog class I am calling the OnLButtonDown as follows

```
void CCPictureCtrlDemoDlg::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

    CRect rect;
    m_picCtrl.GetWindowRect(&rect);
    ScreenToClient(&rect);
    if (rect.PtInRect(point))
    {
        // Do something
    }

    CDialog::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

PreTranslateMessage is only triggered when i hover the mouse over the picture control, it does not trigger when i click on the picture. and the OnLButtonDown of the main dialog is does not trigger when
I click on the picture control, it only triggers when I click anywhere other than the picture control.

Thanks.

Comment: `GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_BITMAP)` will not find itself. You can call it on the parent dialog, but not the control. Nothing wrong with using `m_hWnd == pMsg->hwnd`, though.

Comment: thanks, i have moved the PreTranslateMessage to the main dialog and now it is working but the condition  if (rect.PtInRect(point)) is never true.

Comment: Moving `ScreenToClient` to the dialog naturally translates the coordinates relative to the client area of the dialog. `::ScreenToClient(GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_BITMAP), &point);` fixes that.

Comment: The coordinates provided by `WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP)` are client coordinates relative to the `HWND` that is being clicked on.  So you shouldn't be using `ScreenToClient()` at all. But if you have to do the translation in the parent dialog, then look at `MapWindowPoints()` instead